# Extract E-mail Addresses from Text File (SED? AWK?)

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file of e-mail addresses harvested from Outlook so that the addresses in the harvested form show up like this:

```
-A@b.com
-C@d.com
-A@b.com,JOHN DOE, RICHARD ROE,"\O=USERS:SAM"
```

etc.

What I would like to end up with is a text file that has one validly formed address on each line. So A@b.com would be OK, but "RICHARD ROE" and the "\O=USERS,etc." would not be. Perhaps this could be done with SED or AWK?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I manipulate the text file to extract properly formed email addresses without the cruft?

Comment: Is the email address alway the first part of the line? And it ends with a `,` (comma)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Sometimes the lines end with a comma, sometimes a semi-colon, sometimes double-quotes, ex.:

Comment: Usually a line will contain at least one valid email address, but not always. The problem is the additional material that is not in valid email address format.

Comment: The format of a valid email address is given here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696#page-5 . It seems somewhat complex to check all the special cases..

Comment: Also I believe `-A@b.com` is a syntactically valid email address.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with GNU awk given your posted input file:

```
$ gawk -v RS='[[:alnum:]_.]+@[[:alnum:]_]+[.][[:alnum:]]+' 'RT{print RT}' file
A@b.com
C@d.com
A@b.com
```

It just finds simple email addresses, e.g. "bob@the_moon.net" or "Joe.Brown@google.com", feel free to change the setting of RS if you can figure out an appropriate RE to capture the more esoteric email addresses that are allowed or post a more representative input file if you have examples. here's another RE that works by specifying what character cannot be in the parts of an email address rather than those that can:

```
$ gawk -v RS='[^[:space:][:punct:]]+@[^[:space:][:punct:]]+[.][^[:space:][:punct:]]+' 'RT{print RT}' file
A@b.com
C@d.com
A@b.com
```

Again it works with your posted sample, but may not with others. Massage to suit...

With other awks you can do the same by setting FS or using match() and looping.

Comment: +1 Interesting answer. Now I think `awk` is working like `grep -oE '[[:alnum:]_.]+@[[:alnum:]_]+[.][[:alnum:]]+' file`. However, it might be slower than `grep` since it still does field splitting.. Is there a way to avoid having `awk` do the field splitting?

Comment: No. You can set FS to some value that doesn't exist so there'll only be 1 field per record, but that's not the same as not attempting to do it at all. grep would probably be faster but it's not as extensible but then you'd need to become familiar with GNU grep functionality too. For me, it's easier to just remember the GNU-specific stuff for 1 tool, gawk.

Comment: What about setting `FIELDWIDTHS="5000"` or some other large number. That should presumably prevent field splitting?

Comment: Just like setting `FS=RS`, for example, it won't stop awk from doing field splitting, it'll just result in awk splitting each record into 1 field.

Comment: But at least it should be more efficient than the usual splitting at white spaces? Now we only need consider a single field and there should be no regex pattern matching involved..

Comment: I really don't know. I'd assume the awk code is optimized to handle the case where there's multiple fields separated by white space since that's the normal case so setting FS to something other than a blank char may be less efficient overall even if it results in fewer fields.

Comment: I got in contact with one of the maintainers at Gnu, and he suggested to look at the source code. In the file `field.c` (for gawk version 4.1) line 238, a function called `set_record` is defined. It seems like they are not doing any field splitting unless you explicitly reference `$i`, where `i>=1` or `$NF`. So this is good news :)

Comment: Interesting. They must also be looking for `$var` too, then - basically `$anything-except-zero`. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
awk -F, '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    if ($i ~ /@/)
       print $i
}' file
```

or like this:

```
awk -F, -f e.awk file
```

where `e.awk` is:

```
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /@/)
            print $i
}
```

Comment: awk -F, '
> for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
>     if ($i ~ /@/)
>        print $i
> }' backup02.txt
awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
  >>> for <<<  (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
 extra }
awk: bailing out at source line 5

Comment: @user26732 You have some spurious brackets `>` before `for` and after the `if` and `print`

Comment: I cut and pasted the code; this time I typed it in:  awk -F,'for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /@/) print $1}' backup02.txt
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> backup02. <<< txt
awk: bailing out at source line 1

Comment: @user26732 Yes you are completely right.. It seems I forgot the opening brace `{`, see my update..

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on: $ awk -F,'{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /@/) print $1}' backup02.txt
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> backup02. <<< txt
awk: bailing out at source line 1

Comment: @user26732 There should be a space between `,` and `'` after the `-F` option, and there should be `print $i` not `print $1`

Comment: Creating the e.awk file helped, but there is still cruft including lines like the following:/O=FIRST ORGANIZATION/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=ABC  Such a line obviously doesn't contain an email address.

Comment: The syntax I used was: $awk -F, -f e.awk backup02.txt

Comment: @user26732 Maybe you could provide a sample of the problematic line in your question, or better: If you provide the whole file at http://pastebin.com/ Then it would be easier for us to check for ourselves..

Comment: The line `/O=FIRST ORGANIZATION/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=ABC` works fine with me. That is: it is not printed..

Comment: I did provide an example, it's the line that begins with /O, etc. This is generated by Microsoft Exchange in lieu of a properly formed email address. The problem is that this "address" can show up anywhere in a line, beginning, middle, or end. It looks like, after running your code, that there are no more names in lieu of properly formed email addresses. Because of confidentiality, I can't post the entire file!

Comment: @user26732 Yes I understand that you cannot post the file. Is this: `/O=FIRST ORGANIZATION/OU=FIRST ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=ABC` the *entire* line? Or is there more entries on that line?

Comment: OK, I submitted "eggsample" to pastebin

Comment: @user26732 Can you provide a link to that?

Comment: Like I said, that "O/=First etc" can appear **anywhere**, beginning, middle, end, and there are often variations, so you can't do a simple find/replace.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WaD4qzt8

Comment: @user26732 thanks, I will have a look at it..

Comment: The following `awk -F'[,;]' -f e.awk file` seems to work on the "eggsample".

Comment: Thanks very much! There's still a few, but not many.

Comment: @user26732 You are welcome.. If you can describe the last cases I can have a look at them if you like..

Comment: Is there a way to pipe the output to a new file? The example I was going to pull is exactly the same as in eggsample.txt, so maybe awk hasn't modified the original file and I was just seeing the terminal content.

Comment: @user26732 I am not sure what you mean. But `awk -F'[,;]' -f e.awk file > temp.txt` will save the output in `temp.txt`

Comment: That was the issue, I added ">newfile.txt" at the end of the script and the cruft is all gone in newfile.txt